# jQuery-sortable does not sort after table is rebuild in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the following function to build a sortable table. The table contains a certain amount of columns based on whether it is viewed on a desktop, in tablet portrait or in tablet landscape.

```
function buildTable(platform){

        <!-- javascript for creating table based on csv file -->
        d3.csv("source/data/data.csv", function(data) {
            // the columns you'd like to display
            if(platform=="desktop"){
                var columns = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"];
            }
            else if(platform=="tablet_pt"){
                var columns = ["c1", "c2"];
            }
            else{
                var columns = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
            }

            var table = d3.select("#container")
                .append("table")
                .attr("id","table")
                .attr("class","sortable"),
                thead = table.append("thead"),
                tbody = table.append("tbody");

            // append the header row
            thead.append("tr")
                .selectAll("th")
                .data(columns)
                .enter()
                .append("th")
                .style("background-color","black")
                .style("color","white")
                .style("box-shadow","3px 5px 4px #888888")
                .text(function(column) { return column; });

            // create a row for each object in the data
            var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("tr");

            // create a cell in each row for each column
            var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
                .data(function(row) {
                    return columns.map(function(column) {
                        return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                    });
                })
                .enter()
                .append("td")
                .html(function(d) { return d.value; })
                .style("width","300px");
        });
}
```

When the orientation is changed on a tablet, the container with the table is cleared and the table is rebuild with the new set of columns. However the table is no longer sortable after it has been rebuild. The container is cleared and rebuild with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML("");
buildTable(platform);
```

My question is why the table is no longer sortable after being rebuild and how to restart the sortable plugin on the rebuilt table?

Comment: Technically, after the rebuilt the table is new element in the DOM that has never seen a jquery's `sortable`. Simply, re-call the `sortable` after rebuilding the table.

Comment: That was the problem yes. Thank you.